# How can you search for a user on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, users, profile-page, search

I would like to know how can I search for a Stack Exchange user and see their profile.

Comment: It's obvious in hindsight, but I've had to spend a longer time than I'd like to admit to finding the button too. Not that it's hidden or anything, but if the first two and last two links are question related, I don't ever expect the middle one to be user related.

Answer (score 55):

The [Users tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users) has a search box:

[image]

Type in the name of the user you are looking for and the page is refreshed to show only matching accounts:

[image]

Comment: It seems that the UI for stackoverflow has changed.  This answer needs updating as there is no longer a "User" tab.  The question has become not so dumb after all.

Comment: @SMBiggs: there still is a users tab. It has moved to the sidebar instead of the top, however. If you have enabled the "Hide left navigation" option in your account preferences, you'll have to click on the hamburger menu next to the Stack Overflow logo to see the sidebar navigation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There it is, hiding over there within that modest menu!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I use google in case I'm looking for someone and I don't know their username. For example, if my company is considering hiring a contractor, I like to check and see if the programmer has an SO account. However, I don't know their SO username in this case. If they have included their name in there bio, I can still find them.

Example: Assume I'm trying to find **Mark Murphy**. Searching the users only comes up with usernames of "Mark Murphy".

If I google it like such:

```
Mark Murphy site: stackoverflow.com
```

I see that Mark Murphy is actually CommonsWare, who is the first result of the search. I can see that I've now found the correct person I was looking for when I could not find them on the users page.

Comment: This was my first thought, but because stackoverflow has so many exchanges (each having a different site), it'd be nice to have a way to search them all.